# using if(cin>>) command in c++

Tags: c++, string, cin

I want to calculate perimeter or area of a square.
If user types `c=calculate perimeter` and `a=area`. 
Program jumps after `cin>>a>>c;` commands. What should I do?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int kenar; //kenar means side length
    string c,a;
    cout<<"karenin kenar uzunlugunu girin  :";
    cin>>kenar;
    cout<<"cevre icin c, alan icin a girin  :";// type c for perimeter,a for area
    cin>>a>>c;

        if (cin>>c)
        {
            cout<<4*kenar<<endl;
        }
        else if ( cin>>a)
        {
            cout<<kenar*kenar<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"yanlis giris"<<endl; //cout<<"you type wrong""
        }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to compare something, you should use `>`, not `>>`. `>>` is for reading from input streams.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you should have one variable which would either have the value as 'c' or 'a' based on the user input. You can then use this variable to check what the user has entered as below:

```
 int main()
 {
     int kenar; 
     char option; //note I have changed it to char
     cout<<"karenin kenar uzunlugunu girin  :";
     cin>>kenar;
     cout<<"cevre icin c, alan icin a girin  :";
     cin>>option;

    if (option == 'c')
    {
        cout<<4*kenar<<endl;
    }
    else if (option == 'a')
    {
        cout<<kenar*kenar<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"yanlis giris"<<endl; //cout<<"you type wrong""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin >>c` tries to reads a word into string `c`. `if(cin>>c)` checks if you successfully read a word.

This has nothing to do with the user entering the word `"c"`. You have a variable named `c`. What you probably wanted is `std::string operation`, so you can test

```
if (cin>>operation) {
   if (operation=="c") {
     // ...
   }
   else (operaion=="a") {
     // ...
   }
```